# How can I have tee to wait for all processes?

Tags: bash, shell, process, synchronization, tee

Given the following example:

```
$ echo foo | tee >(grep -o oo); echo bar
foo
bar
oo
```

As you can see, `echo bar` is called before `grep -o oo` has terminated.

(How) is it possible to achieve the following output instead?

```
foo
oo
bar
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the process substitution runs that command in the background.

Put the second echo inside the process substitution.

```
echo foo | tee >(grep -o oo; echo bar)
```

Comment: so the `grep` runs in the background?  Still seems counter-intuitive to me that the `grep` finishes _after_ the terminating `;`, even being in the background.

Comment: `tee` and `grep` are running concurrently, they're both writing to the terminal at the same time.

Comment: Actually, I was wanting to run both commands as separate scripts in a `.travis.yml`. So there is no option to tell bash to wait until all processes have terminated?

Comment: Not as far as I know.